# Problem in Uploaded Webpages on site

Tags: php, html, css, javascript

Warning: include(html\download.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/jamia/public_html/download.php on line 4
this message is displayed when open any page.
it is index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because you are not specifying the correct path, make sure that:

- You are specifying the correct path
- chmod dir to 755

Rather than:

```
include (html\download.html)
```

Try this:

```
include ('html/download.html')
```

Comment: @aamir Fayyaz: Make sure that you have proper dir permissions on server, chmod to 755, try my example as above as well.